Android instrumented tests not all played on some devices
I have an Android app with 225 espresso tests.
Up to now, I have always been able to run all tests in a raw on all devices (Samsung smartphones and tablets, from Android 7 to 14)
I now have a brand new Samsung A15.
On this device, the tests never get to the end of the 225 tests. All run tests passed OK, but they stop randomly, most often between 70 and 120.
At about the time it fails, logcat shows this:
2024-08-26 07:11:07.999  6224-6244  ShellCommandClient      androidx.test.orchestrator           E  Couldn't find a published binder
2024-08-26 07:11:08.015  6224-6244  ShellExecutorImpl       androidx.test.orchestrator           E  ShellCommandClient not connected. Is ShellCommandExecutor service started?
                                                                                                    androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ClientNotConnected: Couldn't find a binder published by androidx.test.services. It is very likely that androidx.test.services was killed, which is usually due to low memory conditions. Consider switching to a device with more memory.

An in the IDE, I get this:
> Task :app:connectedDevelopmentDebugAndroidTest
Test run failed to complete. Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed.
> Task :app:connectedDevelopmentDebugAndroidTest FAILED
FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDevelopmentDebugAndroidTest'.

This is not a issue with the memory size of the device (A15) as it runs perfectly on the A13 with the same memory size and OS (4GB, Android 14) and it also runs perfectly on an A3 with 1.5 GB of memory.
I also rebooted the device, rebuilt all, cleaned the cache of the IDE, deleted 2 apps from the device: androidx.test.orchestrator and TestServices.
It does not help.
I compared all developer settings with the ones of the A13: they are the same.
Any idea of what is happening and how to solve this?

Consider splitting them into smaller batches and running them in separate instrumentation processes. testInstrumentationRunnerArguments in your build.gradle
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
    }
}


Thanks for this idea, but unfortunately, it does not help. Still failing after 40-50 tests

But as I launched a lot of tests, I got a notification from Android saying that "Testservice" is often crashing and has been put to deep sleep.
Maybe a track to follow. Where does this Testservice comes from. I tried to uninstall it, but no change
